# How can I tell which DBs I have access to?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I'm working on a relatively simple query that SELECTs data from several databases.  It looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO ResultTable (theField)
SELECT aField FROM DB1.dbo.tableName UNION
SELECT aField FROM DB2.dbo.table2 UNION
SELECT aField FROM DB3.other.tableName UNION
SELECT aField FROM DB4.dbo.tableName
```

I want to run this query across three servers that are mostly (but not exactly) the same.

On one server, the query works without a problem.  On the second server, my account doesn't have access to one of the databases, which makes the whole INSERT statement fail.
Is there a way for me to check programmatically to see if I have access to a specific database?  I'm hoping for something like this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DB3.sys.table)
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ResultTable (theField)
    SELECT aField FROM DB3.other.tableName
  END
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to generate/populate a table with the databases that you have access to, as I understand it.

You can use the HAS_DBACCESS() function. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/has-dbaccess-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Below is an example of how it can be used:

```
SELECT name AS db_name_, HAS_DBACCESS(name) AS has_access_
FROM sys.databases
--WHERE HAS_DBACCESS(name) = 1
```

Comment: That worked!  In my example, that means replacing my IF statement with `IF HAS_DBACCESS('DB1')=1 `.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sys.fn_my_permissions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-my-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to see your actual permissions.

For example, to see permissions in a specific database:

```
USE YourDatabase
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions (NULL, 'DATABASE');  
GO
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in the example above, the USE statement fails if I don't have access to the database, so I never get to try the fn_my_permissions call.